# Reading input file and inserting text into output file

Tags: bash, awk, substitution

I have an input file called "namelist.txt" with email addresses:

```
user1@domain.com
user2@domain.com
user3@domain.com
```

I am trying to read the addresses from this input file and inserting their values into an output file (newfile.txt) that should read:

```
user "user1@domain.com" with pass"pass" is "user1@domain.com" here
user "user2@domain.com" with pass"pass" is "user2@domain.com" here
user "user3@domain.com" with pass"pass" is "user3@domain.com" here
```

The closest I have come is by using awk:

```
awk '{print "user $0 there with pass"pass" is user $0 here"}' < namelist.txt > newfile.txt
```

This however prints the following:

```
user $0 there with pass is user $0 here 
user $0 there with pass is user $0 here
user $0 there with pass is user $0 here
```

This doesn't print the variable values nor the "pass" value.

I don't know where I am going wrong or whether I am even on the right track, so any advice and / or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Using:

```
awk '{print "user \""$0"\" there with pass \"pass\" is user \""$0"\" here}' file
```

results in the following output on Ubuntu (14.04.2 LTS):

" heree with pass "pass" is user "user1@domain.com 
" heree with pass "pass" is user "user2@domain.com 
" heree with pass "pass" is user "user3@domain.com

Abovementioned code works fine in a UNIX terminal but not in Ubuntu nor Raspberry Pi.

I am confused as to why the differences between distros.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$` variable needs to be outside of quotes and you need to escape the quotes you want to see.

```
awk '{print "user \""$0"\" there with pass\"pass\" is user \""$0"\" here"}' file

user "user1@domain.com" there with pass"pass" is user "user1@domain.com" here
user "user2@domain.com" there with pass"pass" is user "user2@domain.com" here
user "user3@domain.com" there with pass"pass" is user "user3@domain.com" here
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I think I might have another problem as well though.  When I try your answer in an online unix terminal it works perfectly.  However when I try it on Ubuntu (or Raspi) I get different results: " heree with pass"pass" is user "user1@domain.com
" heree with pass"pass" is user " user2@domain.com
" heree with pass"pass" is user " user3@domain.com

Comment: Show any problems you are having in formatted text in your post, it is impossible to read and guess the formatting of what you write in comments.

Comment: Sorry. I have edited the original post to reflect my attempts of using your answer.

Comment: Your input file was created on Windows and so is corrupted with control-Ms at the end of lines. Run `dos2unix` or similar on it.

Comment: For DOS file enablement can put a **{ sub(/\r$/,"") }** clause in your code or if using GAWK you can use **RS="\r?\n"** -- I do this on scripts I build for work because I want to cleanly handle both DOS and Unix files.

Answer (score 2):

You had included the text `$0` inside the literal string but in any case when inserting input data into some formatted string for output, it's usually clearest and easiest to enhance in future if you use `printf` instead of `print`:

```
$ awk '{printf "user \"%s\" there with pass \"pass\" is user \"%s\" here\n", $0, $0}' file
user "user1@domain.com" there with pass "pass" is user "user1@domain.com" here
user "user2@domain.com" there with pass "pass" is user "user2@domain.com" here
user "user3@domain.com" there with pass "pass" is user "user3@domain.com" here
```

and don't use input redirection with awk as that removes the ability for the script to access the input file name. awk is perfectly capable of opening files itself.

Comment: Thx for your insight. I value it highly.